Oscillating body and Doppler effect
Say we have a body attached to a spring, oscillating with some frequency $\nu$. This is one of the simplest problems studied in elementary Physics, and yet I've noticed we always study it positioning the observer in the inertial frame of reference correspondent to the body's point of equilibrium. What would happen if we were moving at some speed $v$ away from this point? Would we observe a variation in $\nu$ if we moved fast enough?

"If we moved fast enough" do you want a relativistic or non-relativistic answer? (The relativistic answer is likely much harder than you might think)

@NíckolasAlves both of them would be great, that way I can compare the classical theory with the modern one

This may help with the relativistic explanation - The more general uncertainty principle, regarding Fourier transforms

How are you observing it?  Doppler is more noticable if you are using sound to observe it.  Observing Doppler in light is typically more demanding.

@CortAmmon I could observe it with a regular camera, whilst moving at a relatively high speed away from the body. Would it oscillate with the same frequency in the recording?
